# Trouble using multiple bootstrap modals (ngx-bootstrap and Angular)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, modal-dialog, ngx-bootstrap

I really have a problem using multiple bootstrap modals within Angular 4. Maybe you can help me out of this. The code is working fine with just one modal. I am not be able to use the buttons/form of the first loaded modal. The second is working fine. After opening and closing the second modal, also the first modal works... strange. Is there something wrong?

```html
<!-- ADD MODAL-->
<div bsModal #addModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myAddModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Dimension</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="addModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupInput">TAG</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input" aria-describedby="keyHelp"
              value="" disabled>
            <small id="keyHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Notice that this field is a surrogate key!</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupInput2">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupInput3">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input" value="">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="dfsdfsdfsdf" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="addModal.hide()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- EDIT MODAL-->
<div bsModal #editModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit {{currentItem?.NAME}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="editModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupInput">TAG</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input" aria-describedby="keyHelp"
              value="{{currentItem?.TAG}}" disabled>
            <small id="keyHelp" class="form-text text-muted">You'll need to delete this entry to change this key value!</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupInput2">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input" value="{{currentItem?.NAME}}">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupInput3">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input" value="{{currentItem?.COMM}}">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="editModal.hide()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal.component';

@Component({

  templateUrl: './dimensions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dimensions.component.scss']
})
export class DimensionsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('editModal') public editModal: ModalDirective;
  @ViewChild('addModal') public addModal: ModalDirective;
  currentItem;

  openModal(item: any) {
    this.currentItem = item;
    this.editModal.show();

  }


  openAddModal() {
    this.addModal.show();

  }


  //Attributes
  public currentVar;
  subscription;
  dimensionData;
  rows;

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {


  }
```

Thank you for your time guys!

Update: By switching the modal sequence inside the code the problem also occures but just in terms of the other modal.

Answer (score 5):

bsModal directive is not really suited for nested modals, please convert to usage of bsModal service, see example here:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-nested

Answer (score 2):

So after a few fixes, production use and testings I can say I have found a solution to a nested ngx-bootstrap modal problems. I have written a service-wrapper for a `BsModalService`.

```
modalIndexing = {};
hasInited = false;

constructor(
    router: Router,
    private modalService: BsModalService,
) {
    router.events
        .pipe(filter((event: NavigationEvent) => (event instanceof NavigationStart)))
        .subscribe(() => this.terminateAll());
}

// Just a modal dude
resolveModal(component, position: 'center' | 'static' = 'center', initialState?: any): void {
    const config: ModalOptions = {
        class: modalClassDict[position] + ' ss-modal',
        initialState
    };

    // For nested launches, wait until previous hide to open new
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.modalService.show(component, config);
    }, initialState.hasTimeout ? 600 : 0);
}

// Modal dude that will return something 
// if you want to of cause, no pressure
resolveModalSub(component, position: 'center' | 'static' = 'center', initialState?: any): Observable<any> {
    const config: ModalOptions = {
        class: modalClassDict[position] + ' ss-modal',
        initialState
    };

    const bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(component, config);
    bsModalRef.content.onClose = new Subject<any>();

    const modalSub = bsModalRef.content.onClose.pipe(take(1));
    this.healthCheck(modalSub);

    return modalSub;
}

// This sneaky little bastard will return something if it hides!
resolveModalSubCheckHide(component, position: 'center' | 'static' = 'center', initialState?: any): Observable<any> {
    const config: ModalOptions = {
        class: modalClassDict[position] + ' ss-modal',
        initialState
    };

    const bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(component, config);
    bsModalRef.content.onClose = new Subject<any>();

    const modalSub = bsModalRef.content.onClose.pipe(take(1));
    this.healthCheck(modalSub, true);

    return modalSub;
}

// This thingy does some pseudo-indexing and cleans up the mess you left
private healthCheck(modalSub, needToCheckHide = false) {

    // The only property ngx-bootstrap modal service
    // is able to return is the number of opened modals
    // so we are heading out from it 
    const index = this.modalService.getModalsCount();

    this.modalIndexing[index] = {
        modalSub,
        needToCheckHide
    };

    // First modal initiates onHide sub 
    if (!this.hasInited) {
        this.hasInited = true;

        this.modalService.onHide
            .subscribe(() => {
                if (_.keys(this.modalIndexing).length) {
                    // This event emits after the modal is closed so its a +1
                    const indexedSub = this.modalIndexing[this.modalService.getModalsCount() + 1];

                    // Handeles the case when you need to know if modal was closed
                    if (indexedSub.needToCheckHide) {
                        indexedSub.modalSub.next(false);
                    }

                    // Completes sub of a value return and cleans itself from dictionary
                    if (indexedSub.modalSub) {
                        indexedSub.modalSub.complete();
                    }
                    delete this.modalIndexing[this.modalService.getModalsCount() + 1];
                }
            });
    }
}

// Termiantes all modal windows in user navigates via back / forward
private terminateAll() {
    _.keys(this.modalIndexing).forEach(index => this.modalService.hide(index));
}
```

Basic usage:

```
const data = {
  // your initial data
};

this.dialogService.resolveModalSubCheckHide(YourModalComponentToDisplay, 'center', data)
  .subscribe((value) => {
      // processing
  });
```

Features:

- Return value handling as subject
- Performance friendly
- Doesn`t leave any uncompleted subjects
- Can return a value if hidden
- Handles unlimited nested levels
- Can be queued to launch modals
- Auto close on manual navigation

Hope this helps somebody <3.